# Python Error: the following arguments are required: experimentname

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am a beginner in Python and PyTorch environment. I am executing the program on [GitHub](https://github.com/noahgolmant/pytorch-hessian-eigenthings/blob/master/example/main.py).
I am getting the following error:

```
usage: main.py [-h] [--self_host SELF_HOST] [--cpu] [--port PORT]
               [--server_port SERVER_PORT] [--config CONFIG]
               [--devices_per_trial DEVICES_PER_TRIAL] [--dataroot DATAROOT]
               [--s3 S3] [--logroot LOGROOT] [--seed SEED]
               [--num_eigenthings NUM_EIGENTHINGS] [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE]
               [--eval_batch_size EVAL_BATCH_SIZE] [--momentum MOMENTUM]
               [--num_steps NUM_STEPS] [--max_samples MAX_SAMPLES] [--cuda]
               [--full_dataset] [--fname FNAME] [--mode {power_iter,lanczos}]
               experimentname
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: experimentname
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback. 

SystemExit: 2
```

Upon %tb, I get following details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/ajinkya/Hessian_Expts/main.py", line 77, in <module>
    skeletor.execute(main)

  File "/home/ajinkya/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skeletor/launcher.py", line 233, in execute
    args = _parser.val.parse_args()

  File "/home/ajinkya/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/argparse.py", line 1768, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)

  File "/home/ajinkya/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/argparse.py", line 1800, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)

  File "/home/ajinkya/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/argparse.py", line 2034, in _parse_known_args
    self.error(_('the following arguments are required: %s') %

  File "/home/ajinkya/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/argparse.py", line 2521, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)

  File "/home/ajinkya/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/argparse.py", line 2508, in exit
    _sys.exit(status)

SystemExit: 2
```

Kindly help to get rid of this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the command that you had use to execute. E.g: `python ....`

Comment: As is evident from the output you have obtained, `experimentname` is required when you run the script. Ensure that you are providing the requisite value for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CLI seems different to the one exposed from [`pytorch-hessian-eigenthings/main.py`](https://github.com/noahgolmant/pytorch-hessian-eigenthings/blob/master/example/main.py). Anyhow, all options prefixed with `--` are options (like `--self_host`, `--cpu`, ...). The only (required) positional argument is `experimentname`, so you need to provide it when calling `main.py`!

An extremely minimal call would be:

```
python main.py my_experiment
```